# Order of execution with multiple JavaScript codes

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have next HTML code:

```
<!-- Virtual Router Section -->
<div id="virtualRouterSection" class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
    {% include "network-virtualRouter.html" %}
</div>

<!-- Zones Section -->
<div id="zonesSection" class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
    {% include "network-zones.html" %}
</div>

<!-- Profiles Section -->
<div id="profilesSection" class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
    {% include "network-profiles.html" %}
</div>

<!-- Ipsec Tunnel Section -->
<div id="ipsecTunnelSection" class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
    {% include "network-ipsecTunnel.html" %}
</div>
```

Each network-* HTML script has its own JS code as follows (network-virtualRouter.html example):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getScript("{% static 'network-virtualRouter.js' %}");
</script>
```

So the question is: How JS codes are interpreted? In mi mind, network-virtualRouter.js will be executed first. After that, network-zones.js, etc.
Is this correct?

Thanks beforehand,

Mike.

Comment: [Yes it is correct. Of course if the js contain an async function, it will execute at the same time of the next one.] edit, see @T.J. Crowder answer instead

Comment: @Richard: Both halves of that comment are, unfortunately, incorrect. :-)

Answer (score 2):

[`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) is *asynchronous*. You're *starting* the process of grabbing the script in the order you see, but those requests may *complete* in any order at all (depending on the size of the resource, thread scheduling on the server, network vagaries, etc.). Whichever ones complete first will get run first, potentially *not* in the requested order.

---

In a comment you've asked:

> However, I would like to execute the JS scripts in the order they are requested. How could i do that?

If I assume you want to make minimal changes (not switching to modules or something), then you could use a promise chain, either with native promises (or a polyfill for native promises) or jQuery's `Deferred` object.

With native promises: Make **each** call to `$.getScript` look like this:

```
var getScriptPromise = getScriptPromise || Promise.resolve();
getScriptPromise = getScriptPromise.then(function() {
    return $.getScript("{% static 'network-virtualRouter.js' %}");
});
```

With `$.Deferred`: Make **each** call to `$.getScript` look like this:

```
var getScriptPromise = getScriptPromise || $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
getScriptPromise = getScriptPromise.then(function() {
    return $.getScript("{% static 'network-virtualRouter.js' %}");
});
```

In both cases, we're using the semantics of `var` at global scope to either create the variable (if it's the first of these in the document) or use the existing variable (if not). If we created it, we create a fulfilled promise. If we didn't create it, we use the promise it already refers to. Then we use `then` to chain from it and make the next call to `$.getScript`. `$.getScript` returns a *thenable*, so returning it from `then` resolves the promise `then` returns to the thenable from `$.getScript`, meaning it waits for that thenable to settle and settles the same way.

End result: Each `$.getScript` call doesn't start until the previous one finishes.

If you want to have all the requests start at the same time, but then run the returned scripts in order, you'll have to use `$.ajax` instead to retrieve the script text, then perhaps [`$.globalEval`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/) to run it when you know it's that script's turn.

Comment: Nice! That is what I wanted to know. However, I would like to execute the JS scripts in the order they are requested. How could i do that?

Comment: @Miguel.G: Added some notes on that.